# Next tag badge: What do "score" and "answers" mean? Like x/yyy

Tags: support, tag-badges

I see the below in my profile:

Next tag badge 
python 
2/100 score 
4/20 answers

What does it mean by 2/100 and 4/20? Does it mean I have 2 and need 100 scores to get the Python badge? Or I have answered 4 times and need to answer 20 times to get the badge? It will be useful if a help message was there near these numbers to explain better.

Comment: Cross site duplicate [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836). From the accepted answer -> "__Bronze__: Have a total tag score of 100 across a minimum of 20 answers" and "A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on __answers__ under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right; that's what it means. You have a net of 2 on all of your Python posts, out of the 100 required to get the tag badge. Along with with that, you have 4 out of the 20 answers required to get the tag badge. See [Tag Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for#68395). And as @toolic said, you can click on the badge to get an informational popup.

Comment: This answer is helpful as a real example of how the tag badge works. Just the explanation can be bit confusing to novice users: "Bronze: Have a total tag score of 100 across a minimum of 20 answers"